# cant change the volume of music after it starts playing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, volume

I am trying to make a simple component that when you press a button, will start playing a looping song which you could control the volume of using a range input.

This is my code so far:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import music from "./assets/music.mp3";

function MusicPlay() {
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(20);
  const testMusic = new Audio(music);
  const playMusic = () => {
    testMusic.play();
    testMusic.volume = volume / 100;
    testMusic.loop = true;
    console.log("started music", testMusic, testMusic.volume);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    testMusic.volume = volume / 100;
    console.log("changed volume", testMusic, testMusic.volume);
  }, [volume]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={playMusic}>Play</button>
      <input
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        step="1"
        value={volume}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setVolume(Number(e.target.value));
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MusicPlay;
```

right now you can press the button to start music, and it will start at the volume you specified, but when you move the slider it doesnt update the volume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every render of this component will create a new instance of Audio. Changing the volume will cause a rerender. This means that you lost the reference to your playing Audio quite a while ago. If you store the audio in a ref, you'll always refer to the same audio and be able to change it's volume:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import music from "./assets/music.mp3";

function MusicPlay() {
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(20);
  const testMusicRef = useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!testMusicRef.current) {
      testMusicRef.current = new Audio(music);
    }
  }, []);
  const playMusic = () => { // consider wrapping this in useCallback too
    if (!testMusicRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    testMusicRef.current.play();
    testMusicRef.current.volume = volume / 100;
    testMusicRef.current.loop = true;
    console.log(
      "started music",
      testMusicRef.current,
      testMusicRef.current.volume
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!testMusicRef.current) {
      return;
    }
    testMusicRef.current.volume = volume / 100;
    console.log(
      "changed volume",
      testMusicRef.current,
      testMusicRef.current.volume
    );
  }, [volume]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={playMusic}>Play</button>
      <input
        type="range"
        min="0"
        max="100"
        step="1"
        value={volume}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setVolume(Number(e.target.value));
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MusicPlay;
```

Comment: thank you, i was just about to write i solved it when you answered haha. I got it to work by either putting testMusic in a useMemo with an empty array for dependencies, or by making testMusic outside of the component function

Comment: @Dario `useMemo` would have a similar outcome, yes, but IMO, conceptually, `useMemo` is best used for immutable data. `Audio` is rather mutable. Anyway, as long as you understand that you need to maintain referential integrity of the one `Audio` instance rather than creating it over-and-over, it seems you are good.